# Angular - Only show a value if there is a string to show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string that is stored in a JSON object which I'm getting from an API. I can't seem to get it to hide using `ng-show` if there is no string to display.

In the actual controller, I get these results when trying various things:

- `string === null` gives me `true`
- `string.length` gives me `Cannot read property 'length' of null`
- `typeof string` gives me `object`
- `angular.equals({}, string)` gives me `false`
- `angular.isObject(string)` gives me `false`
- On the network of Chrome, when empty the string is set to `null`

I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to get the `ng-show` to understand when there is an empty string here. For your reference, when there is a value for `string` it's just a plain and simple `"string"` which is stored in the JSON.

So I just want to check if there is a string there really. Any ideas?

Sample JSON from console:

```
Object {
    name: null
}
```

Comment: Try `string && string.length`

Comment: using string.length? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/length

Comment: @Tushar This does not work.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe As I already said, `.length` doesn't work.

Comment: @germainelol, can you provide your sample JSON?

Comment: As long as `typeof string` gives you `object` and `string.length` does not work there's something wrong with the way you extract the string from your JSON.

Comment: how you generate json? seems like your json serialization a bit wrong

Comment: agree with above - the following utility checks for empty strings : `function isEmpty(string) { return (!string || 0 === string.length);}`

Comment: In javascript, `null` is object :-)

Comment: @xyz If I do `ng-show="name != null"` it still shows.

Comment: @germainelol, what is the result of `ng-show="name !== null"`

Comment: @xyz I just told you?

Comment: @Grundy I believe in Ruby, the API defines it like this `validates :name,     length: { maximum: 200 }, allow_blank: true` but I'm unsure of where exactly it defines the type of object it is returning. I know that when it does return something, it returns a JS `String` object.

Comment: what angular version you use?

Comment: @Grundy right now it's the latest.

Comment: can you update [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMkWEYpqrrkFPiFJzSFe?p=preview)? seems `ng-show` working with _null_ right

Comment: @Grundy You are correct that the plunkr works fine, there must be an issue with the API response, but everything else in this API response works fine. If there is a string sent back it stores it as a string no problem.

Comment: @germainelol, but if plunkr work fine with _null_ value, so your code also should work.

Comment: @Grundy You would think so, but apparently not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92059/discussion-between-grundy-and-germainelol).

Answer (score 2):

Use double negation to convert it to boolean?

```
var isString = !!string;
```

This will convert string to `true` when it exists or `false` when it does not.

All you describe is correct. Type of `null` is an object in JavaScript.

The simplest anyway is just to do the following:

```
ng-show="string"
```

or as I told before maybe more correct because you pass boolean

```
ng-show="!!string"
```

Comment: do not work is not correct JavaScript error. What does it return?

Comment: if I do `console.log(!!name)` I get `false` returned. If I use `!!name` in `ng-show` it still shows my `Name: ...` text which shouldnt be showing as there is no name.

Comment: well, you can't say `ng-show` doesn't work or the `!!name` is returnin incorrect result then (console cannot lie). I just guess you somehow lose the value when you pass it to `ng-show`.

Comment: I am also testing using `console.log()` to see the result

Comment: I did not say you don't. You wrote that you tested it with console, that is why I say this is not a problem of the method how you pass the value. Your problem is somewhere else. You probably just have there a typo or another (isolated?) scope which simply does not have this JSON. Also probably (I assume) you should write here an object reference: instead of `!!name` there should be `!!myobject.name`. Anyway without your code nobody can tell you what is the problem

Comment: I am writing `!!myobject.name`, and when there is a value for `name` it is displayed correctly on the front end. Ideally I would have something like `<span ng-show="name.length && name">Name: {{ name }}</span` but the `Name:` is always being shown even if there is no value for `name` and it is set to  `null` in the response.

Comment: You don't need to check for length... Why do you do that? Empty string will also return you false... And again you don't write here `<span ng-show="myobject.name">`

Comment: I'm not stupid...I'm just making it easier for everyone to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.stringData= "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-show = "stringData && stringData.length">{{stringData}}</div>
        <input type="textbox" ng-model = "stringData">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the other comments/answers, that does not work.